# Is this possible with the Sneak Peak?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have gotten the possibility to get my hands on a pair of Google Glasses. Now I am trying to build a simple application with GDK that does the following:

- By voice command starts the app (WORKS)
- Search in an API for a question (WORKS)
- Displays the result in Static cards (WORKS)
- Load images from internet on cards (DO NOT WORK)

What does not work, and I am trying to figure out if its possible today is to display the result hits with images that I load from the internet. It seems like it can´t be done right now?

Is there any possibility to add a menu on each of these static cards? to have the possibility to for example navigate to the place in the result.

From what I can see, images can be loaded from the Mirror API, but that is data pushed out to the Google Glasses right? Or are there possibilities for me from inside the GDK to ask the Mirror API for data?

Thank you in advance for your help.

My code where I would like the image to load:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
JSONObject advert = adverts.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject address = advert.getJSONObject("address");
JSONObject companyInfo = advert.getJSONObject("companyInfo");
JSONObject coordinates =        
advert.getJSONObject("location").getJSONArray("coordinates").getJSONObject(0);

String companyName = companyInfo.getString("companyName");
String road = address.getString("streetName");

Card card;
card = new Card(activity);

// Here I would like to have images from internet.

card.setText(i+1+". "+companyName);
card.setFootnote("Test");

mCards.add(card);

}
```

Comment: you can't have a menu on static cards, only live and immersions have menus. You can have an image on the card with only the GDK

Comment: Kenny C: Images on cards yes that are loaded as . But images downloaded dynamically from the internet? I have only managed to load images that are in my project when I launch the apk on to the Glasses.

Comment: Yes, you can download images the same way you would with any other android phone app.

Comment: And place them in a static card? I have not gotten that to work. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Post some code of what you tried so far

Comment: I do not have any place in my code right now that tries to print images but I posted a code sample where I would like it to load :)

Comment: As a side note, you do know that placing advertisements within a Glass application (Glassware) is currently prohibited (by the agreement you have when you obtain Google Glass)?

Comment: Im not trying to place ads :)

Comment: My apologies, was misled by "advert" language in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could replicate the card ui using xml and then use LazyList to load them asynchronously. I've tried it and it works great!

The xml I am using is the following. It may be improved but it works. You'll also probably need to add a TextView for the footer since I didn't use it. You can find the metrics for everything here https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/assets/css/base_style.css or by inspecting the playground with firebug or similar https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llImages"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="360px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivImage1"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSecondaryImages"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivImage2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivImage3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMainText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llImages"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only difference is that the main text is not resized depending on its length. I've tried with 3 different libraries but they didn't work as expected, but feel free to improve this if you want. You'll also notice that main text margin-top is set to 10px instead of 40px as playground css. That's because I see some additional margin there when wearing Glass.

Using it from the adapter is like the following. I know it could be improved, but it's just to give you an idea of how to do it ;)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_card, null);

        CustomRowViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomRowViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvMainText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainText);
        viewHolder.ivImage1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage1);
        viewHolder.ivImage2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
        viewHolder.ivImage3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage3);
        viewHolder.llImages = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.llImages);
        viewHolder.llSecondaryImages = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.llSecondaryImages);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    CustomClass cc = values.get(position);

    CustomRowViewHolder holder = (CustomRowViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.tvMainText.setText(cc.getDescription());

    if(!cc.getFiveLastPhotos().isEmpty())
    {
        holder.llImages.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        holder.ivImage1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

        ImageLoader.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).DisplayImage(cc.getFiveLastPhotos().get(0).getSrcPhoto(), holder.ivImage1, null, ImageLoader.NO_ANIMATION);

        if(cc.getFiveLastPhotos().size()>1)
        {
            holder.llSecondaryImages.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            holder.ivImage2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            ImageLoader.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).DisplayImage(cc.getFiveLastPhotos().get(1).getSrcPhoto(), holder.ivImage2, null, ImageLoader.NO_ANIMATION);

            if(cc.getFiveLastPhotos().size()>2)
            {
                holder.ivImage3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                ImageLoader.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).DisplayImage(cc.getFiveLastPhotos().get(2).getSrcPhoto(), holder.ivImage3, null, ImageLoader.NO_ANIMATION);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.ivImage3.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder.ivImage2.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            holder.ivImage3.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            holder.llSecondaryImages.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        holder.llImages.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        holder.ivImage1.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        holder.ivImage2.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        holder.ivImage3.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        holder.llSecondaryImages.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

I hope it helps you, and please post any suggestion you may have

Comment: Do you have an example? Or is there a tutorial?

Comment: Hi Jokez80 I've shared my code, I hope you find it useful

Comment: Pablo: Thank you so much! True hero!